# how to post contact no. to sql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, post

I want to store user's contact no. from an android registration form in SQL database but it shows 'failure' instead of 'success' when i try to add $_post['contact'] code to my PHP file.
This is my PHP file.

register.php

```
<?php
 define('HOST','mysql8.000webhost.com');
 define('USER','a6293046_******');
 define('PASS','*********');
 define('DB','a6293046_insti');
 $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $address = $_POST['address'];
 $contact =(int)$_POST['contact'];
 $institute = $_POST['institute'];


 $sql = "insert into Persons (name,email,address,contact-no,institute)      values ('$name','$email','$address','contact-no','$institute')";
 if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
 echo 'success';
 }
 else{
 echo 'failure';
 }
 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Please tell me what i am doing wrong in it. thank you

Comment: sorry, there is an update::::::  values ('$name','$email','$address','$contact','$institute')";

Comment: what is the data type of contact number in database

Comment: $contact =(int)$_POST['contact']; simply use like this $contact =$_POST['contact'];

Comment: @Arun Kumaresh i am using int datatype for contact no in database.

Comment: I have already tried $contact=$_POST ['contact]  but still php file shows failure..:(

Comment: Subtract 'no' from 'contact'. What do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
     define('HOST','mysql8.000webhost.com');
     define('USER','a6293046_******');
     define('PASS','*********');
     define('DB','a6293046_insti');
     $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $address = $_POST['address'];
     $contact =$_POST['contact'];
     $institute = $_POST['institute'];


     $sql = "insert into Persons (name,email,address,contact-no,institute)      values ('$name','$email','$address',$contact,'$institute')";
     $result=$con->query($sql);
if($result)

{
     echo 'success';
     }
     else{
     echo 'failure';
     }
     $con->close();
     ?>



remove the int for $POST_['contact'] and dnt use single quotes('') for $contact while inserting since it is a integer for string value you should give single quotes
```

Comment: i tried it but after running php file it still shows failure. Did u run it? After removing all the code for contact the php files shows success..don't know wht is the error in the code.plz help me in this

Comment: ..can i contact you somewhere where i get help from you. Please help me. I need this problem to be resolved..:(

Comment: for integer values you should not  use single quotes if you quotes it will become string

Comment: Yeah i got it..and i removed the quotes..but still it shows failure..do you see any more problem in the code??  Could you please run it?? May be you get somthing by doing that. Please

Comment: print the $ sql and run the query in phpmyadmin

Comment: Query is runny fine in phpmyadmin.it is adding data to the table.

Comment: Still showing  failure...:( is this error  related to java class in my android project?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <?php
 define('HOST','mysql8.000webhost.com');
 define('USER','a6293046_******');
 define('PASS','*********');
 define('DB','a6293046_insti');
 $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
 //change 'somename' with the name of submit button!
 if(isset($_POST['somename'])){
     $error=0;
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $address = $_POST['address'];
     $contact = $_POST['contact'];
     $institute = $_POST['institute'];
     if(is_numeric($contact)){
         $error=1;
     }
     if($error==1){
         $sql = "insert into Persons (name,email,address,contact-no,institute) values ('$name','$email','$address','$contact','$institute')";
         $insert= mysqli_query($con,$sql);
         echo 'success';
     } 
     else{
         echo 'failure';
     }
 }
 ?>
```

this code will insert data in database only if $contact is numeric otherwise there will not be insert

Comment: By saying numeric did you mean Int?? Yeah i have declared it int in the database although there is  no such datatype name numeric...i tried implementing your code but while running it shows error in line 26

Comment: I updated the code try again please! What code is on line 26?

Answer (score -1):

`'contact-no'` is not variable.
change `'contact-no'` to `$contact`

try this code

```
$sql = "insert into Persons (name,email,address,contact-no,institute)      values ('$name','$email','$address','$contact','$institute')";
```

Answer (score -1):

Offcoarse it will: you have an mistake in your SQL, you lost dollar sign and you should use $contact variable not $contact-no

```
$sql = "insert into Persons (name,email,address,contact-no,institute)      values ('$name','$email','$address','$contact','$institute')";
```